# Send email from template file

Tags: 7, theming

I am making a return request page for my website the user will enter in his/her information about their order and it will pull up a list of their order. The information is pulled from the views then submitted to the confirmation page.

I already have the form validation working but I need the validation code written in the **page--node--nodeid.tpl.php** to send an email to 2 people, the customer and me, using the information from the form.

I've seen [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7), but this seems like it needs to be used in a module.

Is this even possible?

On a side note it would be helpful to be able to use a template later.

Comment: Writing email logic like this into a template file is a bad design practice. Template files are designed for rendering only. What happens when someone stumbles (e.g. via web crawler) across the page without submitting a form? Why not write the email logic in your submission handler?

Comment: This seems possible. The form that is submitting is also in a template file. How would I send the emails?

Comment: It sounds like you're hacking the theme files to display & process your own custom form. If you want a non-coding solution, [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) will let you create your own custom form that can email on submission. If you need custom PHP processing, look at [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390) on creating your custom form in a module. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.blog.yamandi.com/how-use-drupalmail-function-tutorial) on `drupal_mail` that demonstrates how you would send email in a form submission handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing all of this within templates really shouldn't be the way to go. Write a custom module. And then do the following:

1. Use `hook_menu()` to create a page. Page callback would be `drupal_get_form`. Page argument would be `YOURMODULE_form`.
2. Inside `YOURMODULE_form()` you'll create your form. Check [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) for detailed info.
3. Finally you have to add a submit function `YOURMODULE_form_submit()` where you do your processing and use `drupal_mail()` to build and send your emails.

Maybe look at a [little module](https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-custom-contact-form-block) I once wrote myself that follows a similar approach, form to mail, only it doesn't happen on a page but in a block instead. So that it can be placed on every page you want.