# Is it possible to send Email from Drupal Template File

Tags: emails

I need to send email from a template file. I have already seen [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/171677/send-email-from-template-file) thread and i get the point that its a bad thing to do. Any how i must send email from the TPL file in my case.

Using PHP mail function sends email, but once I add `<img src="test.jpg">` tag, the email is never sent. Any clues what is happening here?

Comment: Definitely don't do that, template files are for outputting content only! Any business logic should be in a preprocess function or somewhere else. Because of the way templates are `eval`'d, you can get strange things happening that are a pain to debug. Put the code where it's meant to go, and if there are still problems, at least you know it's the code itself and not the fact it's running in a template

Comment: Why do you need to send it from a template file? O_O

Comment: i have a complicated logic implemented in template file already so would like the send email right from there,